# Responsive web design in Windows 8.1 IE Snap View split screen

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-8.1

I've written a responsive website that works as it should on phones and in regular resizeable desktop browsers. However, when I'm using IE in Windows 8.1 and snap the browser on the side, the responsiveness seems to be ignored and instead the website is zoomed out and hence get rather tiny text, which is not good. Especially on high resolution screens like on my Surface 3.

Below you can see a screenshot from the same site, one in the IE app snapped to the right side, and one in regular desktop IE resized to roughly the same width as the snapped one.

Is there a way to make the website behave as I want it to in the snapped IE app?

[Live website](http://bibelstudiet.no/) | [LESS source at BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/sdaweb/bibelstudiet.no/src/051e3ece33f49d985c7e7ecc4029cb91511cd8c4/less/?at=master)

---

**Snapped view in IE App**

[image: screenshot of regular IE]

**Regular IE with roughly same width as the snapped one**

[image: screenshot of IE app]

Answer (score 1):

Right before I was about to submit the question I discovered the solution myself hidden in [one of the many Similar Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20963690/39321). Didn't find that one in my initial searching, so posting this question anyways in case it's a "better search target".

```
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
```

*More info at [Internet Explorer Dev Center: Device adaptation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh708740(v=vs.85).aspx)*